# KeyVault -> Databricks automatic integration

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-databricks

I have followed [Create an Azure Key Vault-backed secret scope](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/secrets/secret-scopes.html#create-an-azure-key-vault-backed-secret-scope) to integrate Databricks with Key Vault and all works ok. Unfortunately this requires manual intervention, which breaks our 'full automated infrastructure' approach. Is there any way to automate this step?

Comment: Is there a specific step you want to automate?  Is it the Key Vault tasks, or the scope portion in Databricks?

Comment: scope portion in Databricks. According to documentation you have to go to this url https://<your_azure_databricks_url>#secrets/createScope and do some clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **UPDATE:** You create a Databricks-backed secret scope using the [Databricks CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/) (version 0.7.1 and above). Alternatively, you can use the [Secrets API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/secrets).

---

It does not appear that Azure Key Vault backed secret scope creation has a publicly available API call, unlike the Databricks backed secret scope creation.  This is backed by the 'Note' on the [secret scopes doc page](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/secrets/secret-scopes.html#secret-scopes):

> Creating an Azure Key Vault-backed secret scope is supported only in the Azure Databricks UI. You cannot create a scope using the Secrets CLI or API.

A request for the feature you are asking for was made last year, but no ETA was given.

I took a look at the request made by the UI page.  While the form data is simple enough, the headers and security measures make programmatic access impractical.  If you are dead-set on automating this part, you could use one of those tools which automates the cursor around the screen and clicks things for you.

Comment: Yeah, having some kind of Selenium framework was in our opinion the only option, but we wanted to avoid this if possible.

Comment: @czajek it is possible now to create AKV scope through API, but only with User Principal tokens

Answer (score 0):

Now it is possible, but you can't use a service principal token. It must be a user token which hinder automation.

Refer to Microsoft Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes#create-an-azure-key-vault-backed-secret-scope-using-the-databricks-cli

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Update May 2023: now it’s possible to use service principal to create a secret scope from azure keyvault: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/product/2023/april#create-an-azure-key-vault-backed-secret-scope-with-a-service-principal

You can use [Databricks Terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs) to create secret scope baked by the Azure KeyVault.  But because of Azure limitations it should be done by using user’s AAD token (usually using azure cli). Here is the working snippet for creation of the secret scope from existing KeyVault:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    databricks = {
      source = "databrickslabs/databricks"
      version = "0.2.9"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  version = "2.33.0"
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_databricks_workspace" "example" {
  name                = var.workspace_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
}

provider "databricks" {
  azure_workspace_resource_id = data.azurerm_databricks_workspace.example.id
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                = var.keyvault_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
}

resource "databricks_secret_scope" "example" {
  name = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.name
  keyvault_metadata {
    resource_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id
    dns_name    = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.vault_uri
  }
}

variable resource_group {
  type        = string
  description = "Resource group to deploy"
}

variable workspace_name {
  type = string
  description = "The name of DB Workspace"
}

variable keyvault_name {
  type = string
  description = "The name of DB Workspace"
}
```